# How to programmatically compile Rust programs?

Tags: rust

Given metadata about the library I am trying to create in the form of an expression tree, I would like to be able to convert this into some sort of Rust-specific syntax tree that can be given to the Rust compiler.

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459647/is-it-possible-to-generate-and-execute-rust-code-at-runtime) but it is outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is. The Rust compiler itself. The entire compiler is a library and `rustc` is just a small crate that calls into the compiler. As an example there's the [`stupid-stats`](https://github.com/nrc/stupid-stats) crate. It runs the rust compiler to generate some statistics about the code.

All you need is to import the `rustc` and `rustc_driver` crates (with `extern crate`) and implement the `rustc_driver::CompilerCalls` trait for a type (lets call it `MyDriver`). Then you can run rustc like this:

```
let args: Vec<_> = std::env::args().collect();
let mut my_driver = MyDriver::new();
rustc_driver::run_compiler(&args, &mut my_driver);
```

You need to make sure that the path to the standard library and core library is passed. In my case I added

```
"-L $HOME/.multirust/toolchains/nightly/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib"
```

to the command line. You cannot simply add this to the `args` vector, because `$HOME` isn't parsed here. So you need some more code that extracts the `$HOME` env var and builds your command.

Comment: Thanks. How does one map the expression tree into a syntax tree that the rust compiler understands OR can the compiler only handle rust source code in some text representation?

Comment: phew, that requires a lower level interface than the one I showed. It's certainly possible, but you need to create the AST (the HIR) yourself. I suggest you look at the `librustc*` and see how the rustc binary is created.